# use of deleted function в c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

struct qwer
{
        const int x{1};
};

qwer tt()
{
        qwer xx;
        return xx;
}

int main()
{
        qwer qq;
        qq = tt();

        return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
qwer.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
qwer.cpp:18:10: error: use of deleted function ‘qwer& qwer::operator=(qwer&&)’
   18 |  qq = tt();
      |          ^
qwer.cpp:4:8: note: ‘qwer& qwer::operator=(qwer&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
    4 | struct qwer
      |        ^~~~
qwer.cpp:4:8: error: non-static const member ‘const int qwer::x’, can’t use default assignment operator
```

Объясните пожалуйста в чем проблема )

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь (а может, и ошибаюсь...), компилятор не может сгенерировать  присваивание по умолчанию из-за `const` - он же не может менять константный член...

Comment: когда вы пишите `qq = tt();` в `qq` изменяется `x`, но т.к. `x` это константа то происходит ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При присвоении по умолчанию просто выполняется почленное присвоене полей.

Но у вас поле (член) объявлено как `const`, т.е. присваивать ему нельзя.

Компилятор это выражает своим языком :)